# How should a registry be run in a docker swarm?

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

In docker swarm mode with 2 nodes, if I do:

```
node1master# docker service create --name registry --publish 5000:5000 registry:2
```

then I cannot access the registry by doing:

```
node1master# telnet localhost 5000
Trying ::1...
Trying 127.0.0.1...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused
```

because the registry is now running on `node2worker`:

```
node2worker# telnet localhost 5000
Trying ::1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
```

(of course it could be scheduled on `node1master`, but in this case it isn't)

What I don't understand is why the registry is not connected to the `ingress` network.

What I think makes sense is a registry that is connected to the `ingress` network *as long as docker itself* routes requests for `localhost:5000` through the ingress network.

How should the registry be run so that it either is available as `localhost:5000` on all nodes (using the ingress network I guess), or as some fixed DNS name that works for the docker daemon.

Comment: Hm, i think last time i tried, this worked, but i should check (not at a computer now). Let me add a big **warning** that this trick is nice in a test setup, but that running this makes the registry publicly accessible on **every node** in the Swarm, without access control, so anybody can access your images, and _push_ / _overwrite_ your images (by default, the registry image has no access control)

Comment: @thaJeztah so my problem might also be related to my other question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41405221/how-can-i-use-a-docker-swarm-mode-manager-behind-a-floating-ip, but given the security implications, is there a network that docker itself will see but that is not the publicly accessible ingestion network where the registry can reside?