# How can I use a docker swarm mode manager behind a floating IP

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

Some providers, such as ScaleWay will give your server an IP that is not attached to a local interface on the box.

```
# docker swarm init --advertise-addr <my-external-ip>:2377 --listen-addr 0.0.0.0:2377
Error response from daemon: must specify a listening address
because the address to advertise is not recognized as a system address
```

While

```
# docker swarm init --advertise-addr eth0:2377
```

will advertise a private IP address.

How is docker swarm supposed to be setup in such an environment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an issue with native `swarm mode`, when it comes to binding to a non system `IP Address` as `docker 1.12.5`. There has been multiple github issues, but the problem still persists.

To define non system `IP Address`: `IP Addresses` used with technologies like `DNAT`. These `IP Addresses` are not set on local interface and visible to underlying operating system.

sources: [link1](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/27647), [link2](https://github.com/docker/docker/pull/22663), [link3](https://github.com/rancher/rancher/issues/6473).